# VNC Viewer does not recognize modem ip

Tags: vnc, modem

What could be the possible cause for me to be able to configure the ppp0 signal from a modem perfectly on my Raspberry Pi, but not being able to access it (the rpi) via VNC via the IP provided by the modem? The IP generated by the modem allows me to access the internet in raspberry and even make a connection via socket. But it's no use for me to access raspberry remotely.

***Brazil says:*** Hello! And thank you.

Comment: How do you manage the RasPi? Do you have a monitor and keyboard/mouse attached?

Comment: I usually use VNC itself on my notebook to access it. With the RPI connected via eth0 (network cable). What I would like to do is configure the ppp0 signal so that I can maintain the same access pattern.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you have a modem running that perfectly connects to the internet. You now try to connect to the modems management console via VNC. Modems of this sort usually have a html management site accessible with a browser. It may be possible that you can also connect with VNC but this needs a VNC server to connect to. So please make sure that the VNC server is running on the modem.

If you want to connect from the RasPi to another device (the modem) then you use the VNC client to connect to the VNC server on the modem. A VNC server running on the RasPi does not help. This is if you want to connect from another device with its VNC client to the RasPi.

Comment: The VNC server is present on Raspberry. Also used in eth0 or wlan0 connections, I only have problems with ppp0 connections.

Comment: @CaiodePaulaSilva I have updated my answer. B.t.w. I do not really believe that the modem is accessible with VNC.